# sending an email manually in Django admin panel, and show a successful alert instead of redirect

Tags: django

this my **view.py:**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

def sendmail(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        send_mail('this is subject',
                'Hello alex',
                "mysite.com <orders@mysite.com>",
                 ['reciver_email@gmail.com'],
                 fail_silently=False)
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

this my **app.url.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/redirect/' , views.sendmail, name='sendmail'),
]
```

this my **url.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('register.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

this is my **change_form.html** that override admin templates:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
     <a href="{% url 'sendmail'%}"> <input type="button" value="Click" name="mybtn" /></a>

    {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messagelist">{% for message in messages %}<li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}


    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

and this my **app image**:
[my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Qbu.png)
when I click on the button the email was sent.
[look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFes6.png)
but, I want when the email was sent, just show an alert that email sent successfully.
my problem is, I don't want to redirect to another page. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this tutorial to solve my problem :

[click](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/custom_button.html)